# small php fetch query with "WHERE" issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
$u_ress = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blackjack` WHERE `brukernavn`='$spiller->brukernavn' AND `by`='$by'");
$bj = mysql_fetch_object($qry);
```

This code wont work. It wil only show my $by, but its not what i want. I want it to get from blackjack where brukernavn is ( as it said) AND from by aswell.

How can i this?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM blackjack WHERE brukernavn='{$spiller->brukernavn}' AND by='$by'
```

Notice when doing advanced variables within the string you must use brackets.

Comment: You could also use string concatenation

Comment: Well JSS9534, I tried that in the first place, but that didnt work.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/mafia/public_html/include/blackjack.php on line 21

Comment: If this part is empty ($spiller->brukernavn) and you have properly escaped or concatenated then either the information / property is empty or your $spiller object does not have a __get method. Also, try getting the exact error of the sql and echoing out the statement that is actually being executed.

Comment: The $spiller->brukernavn is not empty.

how do i get the exact error?

Comment: I might get killed for not telling you to use PDO or MySQLi but you can still echo out mysql_error().

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by=''' at line 1

Comment: Echo out the sql statement as well. Put the statement into a separate variable and then echo out that variable. 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blackjack WHERE brukernavn='{$spiller->brukernavn}' AND by='$by'";

Comment: SQL Injection, here we come!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
    echo "Query:=".$u_ress = ("SELECT * FROM blackjack WHERE `brukernavn` ='{$spiller->brukernavn}' AND `by` ='$by'");

$query = mysql_query($u_ress);

    //$bj = mysql_fetch_object($query);
```

mysql_query is not recommended.

Comment: post what you get as an echo

Comment: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mafia/public_html/include/blackjack.php on line 21

what is better then? :)

Comment: tell me what you get after Query:=

Comment: execute the above code the query will be visible to you I want to see the query that is getting executed.

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by=''' at line 1

Comment: is by a column name in database?

Comment: I want the query that gets printed on your screen..you should get the above query printed plz post that

Comment: Query:=SELECT * FROM `blackjack` WHERE brukernavn ='Mafiamakten' AND by ='bob'

Comment: plz clarify you have brukernavn  and by  two columns in database?

Comment: `by` is a keyword in mysql

Comment: @MalinPedersen are you there?